Retrieve State and Country/Territory Picklists translated values from translation workbench
I'm able to retrieve original values throuhg Postman, but I couldn't find any way to retrieve the translated values from Translation Workbench.
Here's my XML:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:met="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <met:SessionHeader>
      <met:sessionId>{{token}}</met:sessionId>
    </met:SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <met:readMetadata>
      <met:type>AddressSettings</met:type>
      <met:fullNames>Address</met:fullNames>
    </met:readMetadata>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

